# Java Sonar Null Caution "null returned but Boolean expected"

Tags: java, sonarqube, boolean

How I can edit this code block as a readable or logical way so that I don't get a warning from sonar?
I need three result `false`, `true` or `null`

```
 public Boolean x() {
    if (...) {
        return true;
    } else if (...) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to return `null`? Wouldn't `false` suffice?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with sonar cube but try `Boolean.TRUE` instead of `true` etc.

Comment: You can just ignore the warning if `null` is a valid return (e.g. `// NOSONAR`), or use an `Optional`.

Comment: @Mark there may be cases where `null` means something like "I don't know" as opposed to a clear "yes" or "no". But as Henry suggested, using `Optional` might be the better way to go if this is possible (the OP would need to change more than just one method).

Comment: can you explain any of `if (...)` conditions?

Comment: `since boolean is a primitive type, it cannot be assigned null`

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo `boolean`!= `Boolean`

Comment: Mark the return type `@Nullable`.

Comment: @Mark if result is null process ended; if true, process start one flow ; false other flow is continuing

Comment: Sorry, my bad, got it. It's the wrapper class

Answer (score 5):

Although you can return null, you shouldn't, at least according to `squid: S2447`

> While `null` is technically a valid `Boolean` value, that fact, and the distinction between `Boolean` and `boolean` is easy to forget. So returning `null` from a `Boolean` method is likely to cause problems with callers' code.

If you disagree you can disable it locally:

```
return null;//NOSONAR
```

Or deactivate this rule entirely in settings

Also discussed in [sonar group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sonarlint/KYCBUVJTcuY/F_YTkr3PAAAJ):

> Many rules also criticize things that I personally do not find bad i.e. "Null should not be returned from a "Boolean" method (squid: S2447)". So I can probably give no good tips.

and [Sonar community](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/new-rule-suggestion-boolean-objects-should-be-used-in-a-null-safe-way-inside-of-expressions/2024) Question:

> I suggest that there should be an extra rule for it.
>
> So a Boolean should not be checked like this:
>
> ```
> Boolean flag = service.getFlag();
> // that's the unsafe call which could cause a null pointer exception
> if(flag) {
>      // do something
> }
> ```

Answered:

> Instead of introducing a new rule, what about using S2447: `Null` should not be returned from a `Boolean` method 1 that prevents a method returning a `Boolean` object to return a `null` value?

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Java 8 use Optional to codify TRUE, FALSE, Optional.empty. It follows the pattern "avoid returning null" and will at the same time suppress the SonarQube warning.

The code would be

```
public Optional<Boolean> x() { 
    if (...) { 
       return Optional.of(Boolean.TRUE); 
    } 
    else if (...) { 
       return Optional.of(Boolean.FALSE); 
    } 
    else { 
       return Optional.empty(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: When you want to return a null, `Optional<Boolean>.ofNullable(null)` seems not work. SonarLint report.

Answer (score 0):

Beside, thanks to using Optional I don't have to check null control.

E.g: my first code block

```
    public Boolean x() {
    if (...) {
        return true;
    } else if (...) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void y() {
    Boolean result = x();
    if (result != null && result == true) {
        System.out.println(true);
    } else if (result != null && result == false) {
        System.out.println("false");
    } else {
        System.out.println("null");
    }
}
```

After that using Optional my code

```
    public Optional<Boolean> x2() {
    if (...) {
        return Optional.of(Boolean.TRUE);
    } else if (...) {
        return Optional.of(Boolean.FALSE);
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

public void y2() {
    Optional<Boolean> result = x2();
    if (result.equals(Optional.of(Boolean.TRUE))) {
        System.out.println(true);
    } else if (result.equals(Optional.of(Boolean.FALSE))) {
        System.out.println("false");
    } else {
        System.out.println("null");
    }
}
```

I removed null control